# Maui windows desktop editor appearance

Tags: windows, editor, desktop-application, maui, maui-windows

I would like to change the appearance of the Editor control in .Net Maui for Windows Desktop.

If you add a standard Editor to page, for example...

```
<Editor WidthRequest="300"/>
```

... a editor control is added which has quite a large amount of empty space between the text and the bottom border line...

[image]

This differs from the editors used in the windows desktop o/s itself which are normally quite compact...

[image]

Does anyone know if it is possible to change this?

Comment: Have you tried `HeightRequest`?  `<Editor HeightRequest="32" ... />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the **VerticalTextAlignment="Center"** to let the text in the center

```
<Editor WidthRequest="300" BackgroundColor="Yellow"  VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
```

Also editor has **MinimumHeightRequest** and **HeightRequest** property as @ToolmakerSteve suggest in the comment, you could also try set these values.

There are also many properties for editor. For more info, you could refer to [.Net MAUI Editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/editor?view=net-maui-7.0).

By the way, editor is used to enter and edit multiple lines of text. If you want only one line, you could also use an **Entry** ([.Net Maui Entry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/entry?view=net-maui-7.0))

Hope it works for you.

Comment: I saw a tutorial and they used the Editor control so I used it too.  However, the Entry control seem far more appropriate and can be resized vertically where the Editor doesn't seem to allow this.  Marked as the answer.